# How to determine a numeric range for a specific factor classification label in R

Tags: r, label

I have a problem with labels. I´m running a hierarchical clustering analysis and I need to label ranges of my data. This is a part of my code, for a specific variable, where I try to label some levels:

```
comisiones[["Monto.Pago.Credito"]] <- ordered(cut(comisiones[["Monto.Pago.Credito"]], c(100.96, 382.30, 866.80, 1040, 11500 )), labels = c("min", "1er Quartil", "3er Quartil", "Max"))
```

I get this structure from an example of the book "DATA MINING AND
BUSINESS ANALYTICS WITH R" (Johannes Ledolter, 2013).

This code truncates some of my data turning them into NULL values and that´s my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `cut(...)`, use the argument `include.lowest = TRUE`, i.e.

```
ordered(cut(comisiones[["Monto.Pago.Credito"]], c(100.96, 382.30, 866.80, 1040, 11500 ), include.lowest = TRUE), labels = c("min","1er Quartil", "3er Quartil", "Max"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve your problem by adding lower and upper values that are slightly above/below your minimum and maximum values to the second `cut` argument.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
cut(1:10, c(3,7,8))
[1] <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  (3,7] (3,7] (3,7] (3,7] (7,8] <NA>  <NA>
Levels: (3,7] (7,8]
```

Add the lower and upper values:

```
> cut(1:10, c(0,3,7,8,11))
[1] (0,3]  (0,3]  (0,3]  (3,7]  (3,7]  (3,7]  (3,7]  (7,8]  (8,11] (8,11]
Levels: (0,3] (3,7] (7,8] (8,11]
```